# Nginx rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, rule

I need a rewrite rule for an nginx server. I'm using joomla 1.5 with sh404sef component to make clean urls.

Now i have installed gtranslate module to make the website multi language. So after installing the module my url's will change.

for example

My orginal url:

http://mywebsite.com/index.php?page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=511&option=com_virtuemart

the sh404sef component will change this to

http://mywebsite.com/men-s/coverall-shirt-in-grey.html

But after installing gtraslate the urls changed like this

I want to replace a url to something different. for example:

http://mywebsite.com/index.php?/ja/page=shop.product_details&flypage=flypage.tpl&product_id=511&option=com_virtuemart

here i have enabled japanese language, so there is a additional string /ja/ added in the url.

This is making problems in the website.

I want a rewrite rule for nginx to replace this url to orginal one without ja

Does anyone have an idea.

Please help me..

--
Thanks in Advance
Tibin Mathew

Answer (score 0):

if you rewrite the url in ngingx your joomla will never receive the /ja request, and consequently will never server the translated content.

you'll have to make the sh404sef component work with the gtranslate url's instead
http://gtranslate.net/forum/gtranslate-fully-compatible-with-sh404sef-t2168.html indicates this should be possible, but doesn't say how